# Google Polymer: Creating movable Iron Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, polymer-1.0

I'm using iron-dropdowns from google Polymer to create a dropdown that, when the user clicks somewhere, the dropdown opens at the location of the click. However, when I implement this, the dropdown no longer functions properly (scroll is off, jumps around type page when resizing the window). This happens when I try to manually set its top and left properties in css. Translating it is no better. I've also tried using the methods positionTarget and moved around the trigger with css (positioned absolutely with left and top again), but that also yielded poor results (same as before). Is there some functionality of iron dropdowns that I'm missing? Any help or idea with how to do this? Any push in the right direction would be helpful :) Thanks!